# OrientDB: traverse only edges with some property

Tags: orientdb

I would like to traverse from a vertex, only following edges that match a particular expression (example: `friendsWith.type="bestFriend"`). How do I do this?

Furthermore, I have to run this operation for a bunch of vertices. Is it possible to keep things organized by the "head" of the traversals? Ideally the return would be:

`[[start1, [list of all the vertices during traversal], [start2, [...]],...]`

Comment: Could you explain better what you want to get ? What should be start2 ? Could you provide an example ?

Comment: Could you accept a javascript function ?

Comment: @AlessandroRota actually a javascript function would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this graph

[image]

I used this javascript function with the parameter rid

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var nodes = [];
var previous=[];
var currently=[];
var b=g.command("sql","select from " + rid);
if(b.length>0){
    var vertex=b[0];
    previous.push(vertex);
    nodes.push(vertex);
    do{
        for(i=0;i<previous.length;i++){
            var vertexOut=previous[i];
            var edges=g.command("sql","select expand(outE('friendsWith')) from "+ vertexOut.getId());
            for(s=0;s<edges.length;s++){ 
                var edge=edges[s];
                var type= edge.getProperty("type");
                if(type=="bestFriend"){
                    var vertices=g.command("sql","select expand(inV('friendsWith')) from "+ edge.getId());
                    var vertex=vertices[0];
                    var found=false;          
                    for(k=0;k<nodes.length;k++){
                        var id=nodes[i].getId();
                        var id_v=vertex.getId()
                        if(id==id_v){
                            found=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(found==false){
                        currently.push(vertex);
                        nodes.push(vertex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        change();
    }while(previous.length>0);
    return nodes;
}

function change(){
    previous=[];
    for (indice=0;indice<currently.length;indice++)
        previous.push(currently[indice]);
    currently=[];
}
```

and with `select expand(node) from (select myFunction("#9:0") as node)` I got

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: This looks really good! Can I ask, would you expect calling this function in javascript on the server to be significantly faster than writing a local script in python (pyorient) that does the same thing (i.e. calling SELECT commands and organizing the results).

Comment: Yes, you can calling this function in javascript on the server

Comment: I mean, is a JavaScript function as fast as an SQL call? Is a client side python script slower than both?

Comment: I think the javascript function on the server side is faster than then client side pyhon script

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select outV().name as start, inV().name as end from(traverse * from friendsWith while type = "bestFriend")
```

you can do it even without traverse.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: The traverse part doesn't work for me, isn't it supposed to be `traverse <edge class> from <vertex>` ? I tried `traverse inE('friendsWith') from V while type="bestFriend"` but it didn't get anything.

Comment: I think, you do not get anything from traverse inE('friendsWith') from V while type="bestFriend" because your vertex not have the property type

Comment: OK, this is making more sense - you are saying I should traverse edges instead of vertices, that way the "while" command gives you the edge properties. How could you do this with SELECT? Say, just two layers down. I know you can do `select out('friendswith').out('friendswith') from E` but I don't know how to specify edge properties there.

Comment: you can specify the edges properties using WHERE condition

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi yes but do the "where" conditions apply to the first or second or both "out('friendswith')" components? Thanks!

Comment: if you want to be sure that both match the condition, you can do something like this : select out('friendswith')[condition].out('friendswith')[condition] from E

Comment: OK, two problems: 
1) it seems I can use an edge condition like `type="bestFriend"` but only if I use `outE` instead of `out` - is there a way to ensure the condition is on the edge not the vertex? 
2) Even with `outE()` I can use `type="bestFriend"` but not `type in ("bestFriend","worstFriend")` Is there another way to check against an array?